# wait for cordova sqlite query before resolving a route

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a route like this, now what I want to achieve is showing appropriate view without showing flashing transition of views to the user

app.js

```
    .state('app.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                }

            },
            resolve: {
                "check": function($location, $cordovaSQLite, $timeout) {
                    return $timeout(function() {
                        console.log('checking...');
                        var query = "SELECT * FROM app_config limit 1";
                        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(result) {
                            if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                                console.log('access granted');
                                return $location.path('/app/home');
                            } else {
                                console.log('no access here');
                                return $location.path('/app/first');
                            }
                        }, function(error) {
                            console.error(error);
                        });

                    }, 10);
                }
            }
        })

.state('app.first', {
        url: '/first',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/first.html',
            }
        }
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
```

Everything works as expected but it shows flashing transition to the user. I'm using ionic 1 and angular 1

Comment: try to avoid transition effect with css

Comment: any suggestion will be much appreciated